# When does a left adjoint between Heyting algebras preserve 1?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders, adjoint-functors

This is an exercise from Johnstone's book *Stone Spaces*:

> Let $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to A$  be order-preserving maps between complete Heyting algebras with $f$ left adjoint of $g$. Show that $f$ preserves binary meet iff the equation 
>   $$g (f a \to b)= (a \to g b)$$
>   holds for all $a,b$.
>
> Can you find a similar condition for $f$ to preserve $1$?

I have already proved the first part, but I cannot find a condition for the second one.
It would be very helpful if you can give a hint.

Thanks!

Comment: `\to` renders as $\to$.

Comment: ¡Bienvenida Paula!

Comment: The question is vague, admittedly, but I'm also curious what Johnstone had in mind. Observe that the first part of the exercise holds not just for Heyting algebras, but any adjunction between cartesian closed categories. Presumably the "similar condition" will as well, so the question could be restated as "When does a left adjoint functor between cartesian closed categories preserve the terminal object?"

Comment: (Of course, when I say the first part holds in a more general setting, I mean with $=$ replaced by natural isomorphism)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the suggestion by Alex Kruckman, let us consider a more general situation. Let $A,B$ be complete cartesian closed categories, and $f : A \to B$ be a functor (between the underlying categories) which is left adjoint to a functor $g : B \to C$. We want to find conditions when

- $f$ preserves binary products, i.e. for all $a,a' \in A$ the canonical morphism $f(a \times a') \to f(a) \times f(a')$ is an isomorphism.
- $f$ preserves the terminal object, i.e. the canonical morphism $f(1) \to 1$ is an isomorphism.

By the Yoneda Lemma, $f$ preserves binary products iff for all $a,a' \in A$ and $t \in B$ the induced morphism
$$\hom(f(a) \times f(a'),t) \to \hom(f(a \times a'),t)$$
is an isomorphism. Now let us compute both sides:
$$\begin{array}{cll} \hom(f(a) \times f(a'),t) & \cong & \hom(f(a),\underline{\hom}(f(a'),t)) \\ & \cong & \hom(a,g(\underline{\hom}(f(a'),t)))\\\\
 \hom(f(a \times a'),t) & \cong & \hom(a \times a',g(t)) \\ & \cong & \hom(a,\underline{\hom}(a',g(t)))\end{array}$$
This shows that there is a canonical morphism (again by the Yoneda Lemma)
$$g(\underline{\hom}(f(a'),t)) \to \underline{\hom}(a',g(t))$$
which is an isomorphism for all $a',t$ iff $f$ preserves binary products (Yoneda once again).

Similarly, $f(1) \to 1$ is an isomorphism iff for all $t \in B$ the induced morphism
$$\hom(1,t) \to \hom(f(1),t) \cong \hom(1,g(t))$$
is an isomorphism, i.e. $g$ induces isomorphisms on "global sections".

Actually the same proofs work when $A,B$ are symmetric monoidal categories and $f$ is an oplax monoidal functor, for which we want to find conditions that it is a strong monoidal functor. Here is an example from algebraic geometry: If $f : X \to Y$ is a morphism of ringed spaces, then $f^* : \mathsf{Mod}(Y) \to \mathsf{Mod}(X)$ is strong monoidal. For example, $f^* \mathcal{O}_Y \cong \mathcal{O}_X$ since $f_*$ induces isomorphisms on global sections (by the very definition of $f_*$).

If $A,B$ are complete Heyting algebras (i.e. skeletal complete cartesian closed categories), we have $\hom(1,t) = \{\mathrm{id}_1\}$ for $t=1$ and $=\emptyset$ otherwise. This shows: $f(1)=1$ iff $g^{-1}(\{1\})=\{1\}$.

Comment: Hmm... the condition $g^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{1\}$ is certainly equivalent to $f(1) = 1$ for Heyting algebras, but it doesn't seem "similar" to $g(f(a)\rightarrow b)=a\rightarrow g(b)$, so I suspect this isn't what Johnstone had in mind as the solution to the exercise.

Comment: I'll award you the bounty before it expires tomorrow if no one comes up with any better condition (the original question and the bounty are about the question in the title - the OP and I understand the first half about $f$ preserving binary meets/products)

Comment: There is no formulation which is free from $1$.

Comment: I didn't want a formulation free from $1$... I like the "$g$ induces isomorphisms on global sections" characterization quite a bit, I just wish it had reformulation for posets that felt more like the solution to the exercise. Anyway, bounty awarded.

Answer (score 2):

I've been thinking about this question for a bit. It seems to me that we can't be looking for an answer too "similar" to $g(fa\to b)=a\to gb$ because this is an equation in $A$, and such an equation will not (I believe) suffice for $f1=1$. The idea is that requiring $f1=1$ asks that "$1\in B$ must be in the image of $f$", whereas requiring $f$ to be meet-preserving doesn't ask that "every meet in $B$ must be of the form $f(a_1\wedge a_2)$ for some $a_1,a_2\in A$".

So, in my opinion, a reasonable answer to the question would be to come up with an indirect way of writing $1\in B$ in terms of $\to$ and then simply require $f1$ to equal that expression. For example, it turns out that $1=fa\to f1$ for all $a\in A$, and thus we could say that $f$ preserves 1 if and only if
$$f1=fa\to f1$$
for all $a\in A$. I am not totally satisfied with this answer, but I will at least prove it.

> **Proof:** Let's first establish what properties we can use. Since $B$ is a Heyting algebra we have
>   $$\tag{1}b\wedge c\leq d\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad b\leq c\to d$$
>   for all $b,c,d\in B$. We are also given that $f$ is left adjoint to $g$, which means that
>   $$\tag{2}fa\leq b\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad a\leq gb$$
>   for all $a\in A$ and all $b\in B$.
>
> Now since $f1\leq f1$ we have $1\leq g(f1)$ by (2), so if $a\in A$ then we have $fa\leq f1$ by (2) again because $a\leq 1\leq g(f1)$. Therefore $1\wedge fa\leq f1$ for all $a\in A$, and as such $1\leq fa\to f1$ for all $a\in A$ by (1). Hence $fa\to f1=1$ for all $a\in A$.